# Send incoming http.request with a file to another server error NextPart: EOF

Tags: rest, http, go

I'm having a problem.I want to make a Post request with a small audio_file to a server, make some validation and send it to another server where the file will be processed. I can't receive the file in the second, I always get this error message:

> "multipart: NextPart: EOF"

here is my code:
server one

```
func (ann *AnnoucementController) UploadFile(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    var err error

    // Maximum upload of 10 MB files
    r.ParseMultipartForm(10 << 20)

    file, handler, err := r.FormFile("audio_file")
    if err !=nil{
        errs.HTTPErrorResponse(w, *ann.App.Log, errs.E(errs.Type(errs.EFILE), err))
        return
    }
    defer file.Close()
    ann.Log.Info().Msg("Uploaded File:" + handler.Filename + " File Size:" + fmt.Sprintf("%#v", handler.Size) + "MIME Header: " + fmt.Sprintf("%#v", handler.Header))

    url := "http://localhost:8083/teste"

    body, _:= io.ReadAll(r.Body)

    r.Body = io.NopCloser(bytes.NewReader(body))

    proxyReq, err := http.NewRequest(req.Method, url, bytes.NewReader(body))

    proxyReq.Header = req.Header

    httpClient := http.Client{}
    res, err := httpClient.Do(proxyReq)
    if err != nil {
        return errs.E(errs.Type(errs.EAPICONNECTION), err)
    }

    defer res.Body.Close()

    if res.StatusCode != http.StatusOK{
        return errs.E(errs.Type(errs.EAPIBNOT200), errors.New("status code: "+strconv.Itoa(res.StatusCode)))
    }

    if err = apiCommon.HTTPWrite200JsonResponse(w); err != nil{
        errs.HTTPErrorResponse(w, *ann.App.Log, err)
        return
    }
}
```

on the second server I have this:

```
func (obj *ObjectController) CreateObject(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    file, handler, err := r.FormFile("audio_file")
    if err != nil {
        obj.Log.Warn().Msg("Error Retrieving the File")
        errs.HTTPErrorResponse(w, *obj.Log, errs.E(errs.Type(errs.EJSON), err))
        return
    }
...
```

maybe the file is not being sent to the second server?

Comment: please can you share [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)